# No internet in Azure's VM after installation

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I've setup VM without public IP, on a VNET with default DNS servers (provided by azure). My network security group allows port 80 and 443 (inbound).

I can't access any site in IE once I connect through RDC. `nslookup` works but pinging sites like `google.com` doesn't. Shouldn't it be possible by default? What can I check?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Internet Explorer Advanced Security

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chenley/2011/03/10/how-to-turn-off-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration/

Comment: It's already turned off.

Comment: Did you deploy this to a new virtual network or an existing one? What OS are you using also?

Answer (score 0):

Use network watcher to troubleshoot

```
 $rgName = "ContosoRG"
$sourceVMName = "MultiTierApp0"

$RG = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $rgName
$VM1 = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName | Where-Object -Property Name -EQ $sourceVMName

$networkWatcher = Get-AzNetworkWatcher | Where-Object -Property Location -EQ -Value $VM1.Location 

Test-AzNetworkWatcherConnectivity -NetworkWatcher $networkWatcher -SourceId $VM1.Id -DestinationAddress 8.8.8.8 -DestinationPort 80
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-connectivity-powershell#validate-routing-issues